# LINQ query to find if items in a list are contained in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
List<string> test1 = new List<string> { "@bob.com", "@tom.com" };
List<string> test2 = new List<string> { "joe@bob.com", "test@sam.com" };
```

I need to remove anyone in test2 that has @bob.com or @tom.com.

What I have tried is this:

```
bool bContained1 = test1.Contains(test2);
bool bContained2 = test2.Contains(test1);
```

`bContained1 = false` but `bContained2 = true`. I would prefer not to loop through each list but instead use a Linq query to retrieve the data. bContained1 is the same condition for the Linq query that I have created below:

```
List<string> test3 = test1.Where(w => !test2.Contains(w)).ToList();
```

**The query above works on an exact match but not partial matches.**

I have looked at other queries but I can find a close comparison to this with Linq. Any ideas or anywhere you can point me to would be a great help.

Comment: You've got a typo in your code somewhere. "test" used in your 2nd code block is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Your sample code still doesn't compile. test1.Contains(test2); Linq Contains<T> doesn't take a list of items, it takes a single item.

Comment: ```var list3 =  test2.Where(x => !test1.Any(y => x.Contains(y)));```
Boom tested here on https://dotnetfiddle.net/pB0t42

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
var test2NotInTest1 = test2.Where(t2 => test1.Count(t1 => t2.Contains(t1))==0);
```

Faster version as per Tim's suggestion:

```
var test2NotInTest1 = test2.Where(t2 => !test1.Any(t1 => t2.Contains(t1)));
```

Comment: The code didn't remove any records the value of test2NotInTest1 is exactly what is in test2. Also I had to change the code because t1.count doesn't exists. This is what I changed it to:

var test2NotInTest1 = test2.Where(t2 => test1.Count(t1 => t1.Contains(t2)) == 0);

Comment: `Count(...) == 0` could be replaced by `Any` or `All` (depending on how you want your logic structured), which would be more efficient, since it can stop searching once it's found one.  Also, consider using `EndsWith` instead of `Contains`, since otherwise, e.g. the `@bob.com` filter would eliminate `joe@bob.com.some.other.com`.

Comment: Something is still odd with the second one. I think you want not-Any, and I don't think Any compares to 0. See Tim S' answer.

Comment: Using MoreLinq, could we convert test1 to a HashSet, then find if the item exists in that hash set to gain a performance boost? Eg  `var test1HashSet = test1.ToHashSet()` to create the HashSet with 1 iteration of test1 then `var test2NotInTest1 = test2.Where(t2 => !test1HashSet.Contains(t2))` should be able to produce the results with 1 iteration of test2, performing the check in constant time

Comment: Thanks for this useful tips. Works fine for me.

Comment: How is this an answer? The question was "LINQ query to find if items in a list are contained in another list" -> This answer here gives code to check if the items are NOT in the list.

Comment: From the question: "I need to remove anyone in test2 that has @bob.com or @tom.com." The OP has also said, "This works perfectly. Thanks for the assist."

Answer (score 34):

For those who came after reading **heading** of the question :

```
bool doesL1ContainsL2 = l1.Intersect(l2).Count() == l2.Count;
```

L1 and L2 are both `List<T>`

A simple explanation is : If resulting Intersection of two iterables has the same length as that of the smaller list (L2 here) ,then all the elements must be there in bigger list (L1 here)

---

For those who read the *whole* question

```
var list3 =  test2.Where(x => !test1.Any(y => x.Contains(y)));
```

Comment: This answer is not right since the OP wanted to check the partial match as well. This answer will work only if `l1` is completely covered by `l2`. Therefore, say `"@bob.com"` exists in the `l2`, but not `"@tom.com"`. The result of `doesL1ContainsL2` will be `false`. That's not what OP wanted.

Comment: @hastrb, some people came here after seeing the heading of the question.

Answer (score 15):

```
var output = emails.Where(e => domains.All(d => !e.EndsWith(d)));
```

Or if you prefer:

```
var output = emails.Where(e => !domains.Any(d => e.EndsWith(d)));
```

Answer (score 5):

No need to use Linq like this here, because there already exists an extension method to do this for you.

`Enumerable.Except<TSource>`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx

You just need to create your own comparer to compare as needed.

Comment: It's not possible (AFAICT) to write an `IEqualityComparer<>` that follows the normal rules of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` while doing what he's looking to do.  You could implement the `Equals` with `x.EndsWith(y) || y.EndsWith(x)` and the `GetHashCode` with `0`, but you lose the ability to know which should be the email and which should be the domain, and any benefits of using hash codes.

Answer (score 4):

something like this:

```
List<string> test1 = new List<string> { "@bob.com", "@tom.com" };
List<string> test2 = new List<string> { "joe@bob.com", "test@sam.com" };

var res = test2.Where(f => test1.Count(z => f.Contains(z)) == 0)
```

Live example: [here](http://rextester.com/HMJNV39527)

Comment: better to use test2.Where(f => !test1.Any(z => f.Contains(z)));

Answer (score 3):

```
List<string> test1 = new List<string> { "@bob.com", "@tom.com" };
List<string> test2 = new List<string> { "joe@bob.com", "test@sam.com", "bets@tom.com" };

var result = (from t2 in test2
              where test1.Any(t => t2.Contains(t)) == false
              select t2);
```

If query form is what you want to use, this is legible and more or less as "performant" as this could be.

What i mean is that what you are trying to do is an O(N*M) algorithm, that is, you have to traverse N items and compare them against M values. What you want is to traverse the first list only once, and compare against the other list just as many times as needed (worst case is when the email is valid since it has to compare against every black listed domain).

`from t2 in test` we loop the email list once.

`test1.Any(t => t2.Contains(t)) == false` we compare with the blacklist and when we found one match return (hence not comparing against the whole list if is not needed)

`select t2` keep the ones that are clean.

So this is what I would use.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
List<string> test1 = new List<string> { "@bob.com", "@tom.com" };
List<string> test2 = new List<string> { "joe@bob.com", "test@sam.com" };
var output = from goodEmails in test2
            where !(from email in test2
                from domain in test1
                where email.EndsWith(domain)
                select email).Contains(goodEmails)
            select goodEmails;
```

This works with the test set provided (and looks correct).

Comment: yeah, I've since deleted my comment.

Answer (score -3):

I think this would be easiest one:

```
test1.ForEach(str => test2.RemoveAll(x=>x.Contains(str)));
```

Comment: This is not a LINQ-query, because it creates side effect.

Comment: what kind of side effect r u talking about? can u plz explain... @Mephy

Answer (score -3):

```
List<string> l = new List<string> { "@bob.com", "@tom.com" };
List<string> l2 = new List<string> { "joe@bob.com", "test@bob.com" };
List<string> myboblist= (l2.Where (i=>i.Contains("bob")).ToList<string>());
foreach (var bob in myboblist)
    Console.WriteLine(bob.ToString());
```

Comment: Please also provide an explanation of what your code does and why it helps, code dumps without explanation are rarely of use