# Collection.containsAll implementation in c#

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I need a method similar to Collection.containsAll of java (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection))

I found ISet.IsSubsetOf, but it is defined in ISet. I need similar one in IList.

Is there any similar ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the trick with [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method

```
var count = list1.Except(list2).Count();
if(count == 0) 
{
   // arrays contains same elements
}
```

Or you can get bool result directly with using [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method:

```
bool control = !(list1.Except(list2).Any());
```

It would be better if we use [negation operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2.aspx) because Any returns true if there is any different element.

Comment: yep, sorry, my fault. It's hard to think normally at 6:00 am

Comment: I think you have the right idea with using the `Except` method, but I have several concerns: 1) your comment regarding "exactly same elements" is not correct (and not what the question asks for), 2) the `Any` method should always be used instead of the `Count` method here, 3) it's not clear what `list1` and `list2` are (and the order is important), 4) it's not clear how `count==0` or `control` relate to the question's request for a `ContainsAll` method, 5) your final comment about the negation operator is not clear, and under some interpretations would not be correct (see #1).

Comment: @280Z28 you right i shouldn't say exactly.first I couldn't think  using Any and count came to my mind. list1 and list2 seems clear to me. OP ask for implementation, so here `count==0` is just a control whether there is any  different element or not.so that is kind a different logic but still it is doing it's job very well.

Answer (score 5):

You could write this using LINQ. To check that all elements in `inner` are contained in `outer`, use:

```
inner.All(outer.Contains)
```

If the collections are large, then you should ensure that the type for `outer` provides fast lookups. If not, you might be better off converting it to a `HashSet<T>` first.

**Edit**: You can package this into your own extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> inner)
    {
        return inner.All(source.Contains);
    }

    public static bool Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> inner, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        return inner.All(element => source.Contains(element, comparer));
    }
}
```

Comment: The nice thing about the `source.Execpt(inner).Any()` method over the `inner.All(souce.Contains)` method is in the current implementation it does that `HashSet<T>` conversion for you to make it faster.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Which will lead to terrible performance if `Except` needs to be called repeatedly (for several small collections of `inner`). I'd rather leave it up to the user to decide whether to convert or not.

Comment: I would not say "terrible", also in my experiences the tipping point for the difference in speed has been typically collections below 50 in length and I have seen it as low as 14. And even then the speed improvement of not constructing the HashSet is only marginal.

Comment: As you mention, it depends heavily on the specific scenario. However, for a large `outer` (running into 100s of MBs), calling `inner.All(source.Contains)` over a preconstructed `HashSet<T>` would be drastically faster than calling `Except`.

Comment: The point that I was trying to get across is that, in the absence of further information about the scenario, I would rather leave the optimizations up to the user, rather than enforce a mandatory optimization that would backfire in some cases.

Comment: Good point, I removed the comment. And I agree with you, we need more information if he is using a `HashSet` for one of the two collections using [`IsSupersetOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`IsSubsetOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be better than `Execpt` or `Any`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method that performs the operation using the `Except` and `Any` methods already provided. The advantage of using these methods over `All` and `Contains` is it allows the framework to optimize the implementation of `Except` independently of this method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines if <paramref name="source"/> contains all elements present in <paramref name="elements"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of elements stored in the collections.</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">The source collection.</param>
/// <param name="elements">The collection elements to test for in <paramref name="source"/>.</param>
/// <returns><see langword="true"/> if <paramref name="source"/> contains all elements in <paramref name="elements"/>; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.</returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
/// <para>If <paramref name="source"/> is <see langword="null"/>.</para>
/// <para>-or-</para>
/// <para>If <paramref name="elements"/> is <see langword="null"/>.</para>
/// </exception>
public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> elements)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (elements == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("elements");

    return elements.Except(source).Any();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a .ContainsAll operator in linq but you can use a combination of others:

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656582/linq-query-to-find-if-items-in-a-list-are-contained-in-another-list) article:

```
var test2NotInTest1 = test2.Where(t2 => test1.Any(t1 => t2.Contains(t1))==0);
```