# LINQ to check whether a list<T> is subset of another list<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I am having two list of Users class i.e UsersExisting, UsersToUpdate.
Class Structure is like below.

```
public class Users
{
    public string Name{get;set}
    public Roles[] AvailableRoles{get;set}
}

class Roles
{
    public int Serial{get;set}
    public string Name{get;set}
    public bool IsActive{get;set}
}
```

I have to check whether UsersToUpdate has already all the Role details of UsersExisting.

Eg. This is the list

```
UsersExisting.AvailableRoles={{1,"admin",true},{2,"hr",false},{3,"it",true}};
UsersToUpdate.AvailableRoles={{1,"admin",true},{2,"hr",false},{3,"it",true},{4,"finance",false}};
```

How to do this with LINQ.

I am doing like this.

```
bool isUsersUpdated = !UsersExisting.AvailableRoles
.Except(UsersToUpdate.AvailableRoles).Any();
```

This is throwing error.

Comment: `users_true list is subset of users` - Seems to me the other way around, users is a subset of users_true.

Comment: Check this question and answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332973/261050)

Comment: What data types you are using? What is `{1,admin,true}`? Provide class description and show us your attempt. There is only some pseudo-code. We cannot reproduce your issue

Comment: I don't think that link totally answers question. We even don't know what code OP using currently and what problem he has. Voting for close

Comment: This should be simple in general, all that you need is whether a given subset elements are there in the parent collection, check this link too:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656582/linq-query-to-find-if-items-in-a-list-are-contained-in-another-list

However please remember except the simple types like int, string, you have to override object method's Equals and GetHashCode for valid subset comparison

Comment: @Sergey Have added all the details.

Answer (score 0):

I think the extension method you are looking for here is the Intersect - in your situation you are looking to get no results back to show that it doesn't exist in the super list

```
if(!UsersToUpdate.AvailableRoles.Intersect(UsersExisting.AvailableRoles).Any())
{
      //your code here    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your lists are lists of `Role` objects, you probably don't want to use `Contains` (or `Except`) since that will only tell you whether *those specific object instances* are in the list - in other words, it compares the object *references*, not the object *contents*. (Unless, that is, you change the meaning of "equals" for your class, per @poke's answer).

However, I imagine that the `Serial` property of a Role is a unique identifier that you can use for this purpose - in which case you can do something like this:

```
bool isUsersUpdated = !UsersExisting.AvailableRoles.Select(r => r.Serial)
                      .Except(UsersToUpdate.AvailableRoles.Select(r => r.Serial))
                      .Any();
```

(Although personally I would structure the query differently).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your question is still rather incomplete. You didn’t say waht error you get there. So here’s a working example. Note that as Mrinal Kamboj mentioned, you need to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for your custom type in order to filter them out:

```
List<Roles> existing = new List<Roles>
{
    new Roles(1, "admin", true),
    new Roles(2, "hr", false),
    new Roles(3, "it", true)
};
List<Roles> available = new List<Roles>
{
    new Roles(1, "admin", true),
    new Roles(2, "hr", false),
    new Roles(3, "it", true),
    new Roles(4, "finance", false)
};

bool isUsersUpdated = !existing.Except(available).Any();
Console.WriteLine(isUsersUpdated);


// modified Roles class
class Roles
{
    public int Serial { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public Roles(int serial, string name, bool isActive)
    {
        Serial = serial;
        Name = name;
        IsActive = isActive;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Roles other = obj as Roles;
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return Serial == other.Serial && Name == other.Name && IsActive == other.IsActive;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return new { Serial, Name, IsActive }.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```