# sorting by using linq comparing two lists?

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 list of items;

```
IEnumerable<Investigator> investigators = RepositoryContext.InvestigatorRep.GetInvestigators(site.Site.Id, out totalCount);

var NewInvestigators = base.ActivePage.Investigators;
```

I have 30 items in investigators and 20 items in NewInvesigators, both have property Id, InvId I need to match that.

```
     var all = investigators.Where(b => crInvestigators.Any(a => a.InvestigatorId == b.Id));
```

I tried this but not worked
I want to create a new list based on matching Id of those two lists. If Id matches get the particular investigator(basically a sort on investigators based on Id existing in NewInvesigators).

I can do it by using for each, but I want to know whether it is possible with `linq`?

in newinvestigator I have object which is having two property, investigatorId and Name.

In Investigator I have property Id , City , country.
no Name or investigatorId in the investigator list.

Comment: yes use join in linq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ query to find if items in a list are contained in another list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656582/linq-query-to-find-if-items-in-a-list-are-contained-in-another-list)

Comment: It is possible with Linq Obviously .use join

Comment: no join, no common feild

Comment: Why down-vote, this is a valid question

Comment: someone don't even read, simply doing downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = investigators.Where(inv=>NewInvestigators.Any(ninv=>ninv.id == inv.investigatorId))
                          .OrderBy(inv=>inv.id);
```

Another way to get the same result is using a `join`.

```
var result = from inv in investigators
             join ninv in NewInvestigators
             on inv.id equals ninv.investigatorId 
             order by inv.id
             select inv;
```

Comment: The solution is correct so I don't see a reason why someone would down vote, only point I see is OP is also looking for Sorting too and this solution would have O(N^2) time complexity, which can be improved upon.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Thank you. I added the ordering also.

Comment: I don't have the exact data in both list, just think in investigator I have Id, and in new Investigators  I have InvestigatorId. I need to match that and sort.

Comment: in newinvestigator I have object which is having two property, investigatorId and Name.

In Investigator I have id,city,country

Comment: This is a good solution, check I have another version available which creates the `Hashset` of the `Id` and then do the compare, only benefit of doing that is total time complexity would be `O(NLogN)`, instead of `O(N^2)` out here, but for your kind of data, there will not be much difference, will make difference for very large values of N

Comment: @sreevidya please try the update. I relied on the fact that you said you have two ids. Apparently, we have to change the name of one `id` to `investigatorId` .