# LINQ check if a list contains any item from another list mysql syntax error

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I'm using LINQ with MySql

Mysql version: `5.7.21-log`

EntityFramework : `v6.0.0.0`

Mysql.Data : `v6.9.12.0`

MySql.Data.Entity.EF6: `v6.9.12.0` (I'm not using `MySql.Data.Entity`)

**Query**

```
var keywords = new List<string>();
keywords.Add("keyword1");
var query = dbContext.ads.Where(x => keywords.Any(y => x.Title.Contains(y)));
```

**Explanation**
`ads` is a table in database, sample data:
[image]

Get records where `Title` contains any of the `keyword`

**Exception**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%keyword1%))) AS `GroupBy1`' at line 10
```

**Complete Exception:**

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%keyword1%)' at line 10
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ExamBuilder.Controllers.ExamController.EnterExam()
```

**Internal SQL query**

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`packageMasterId`, 
`Extent1`.`title`, 
`Extent1`.`packageStatus`, 
`Extent1`.`packageCreationDate`, 
`Extent1`.`basePrice`, 
`Extent1`.`validity`
FROM `package_master` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT
1 AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
1 AS `X`) AS `SingleRowTable1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`tile` LIKE %keyword1%)
```

How can I modify the query to get those recrods whose `title` contains any of the `keyword`?

**Update:**

**Question is not duplicate**
The linked question uses same query that I have used but i'm getting exception with mysql!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ query to find if items in a list are contained in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656582/linq-query-to-find-if-items-in-a-list-are-contained-in-another-list)

Comment: @ArunPratap I'm using the same query which is mentioned in the question that you linked as duplicate but i'm getting exception with mysql

Comment: hi please change your question headings and update your question with some more context because your error message doesn't match with your questions heading that you wanted to ask

Comment: I don't understand this exception. I use LINQ a lot. Every day basically. And I have never seen the LINQ libraries throw this kind of error. What is `db.ads`? What is the `query` variable?

Comment: I have updated the question, please check now

Comment: Could you update your question with the generated SQL query?

Comment: What version of entity framework and mysql are you using?

Comment: What version of `MySql.Data.Entity` are you using?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I have updated the question, please check

Comment: How are you configuring the context provider? could you add the relevant config section? I find it hard to believe that you arent using `MySql.Data.Entity` in your project. Can you add part of your DbContext class?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to reproduce your error with the versions of `Entity Framework` and `MySql.Data.*` libraries. Bumping the version to the highest `6.*.*` available could not help, so here is my workaround using the `SqlQuery`.

```cs
 var keywords = new List<string>() { "Test123", "TestASD" };

 var likeStatements = keywords.Select(keyword => $"title LIKE '%{keyword}%'");
 var whereClauseBody = string.Join(" OR ", likeStatements.ToArray());

 var query = context.Ads
                    .SqlQuery($"select * from stack_linq.ads where {whereClauseBody};");
```

Notes:

- `stack_linq` is the schema name. Change it to your schema name. If you have the schema name specified by default in your `<connectionStrings>` then the `SqlQuery` can be changed to `$"select ads where ...`
- in `title LIKE ...` change the name of the column (e.g. if it should be `Title` instead of `title`)
- My `App.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StackMySqlContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=stack_linq;uid=root;password=mysql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Links I've found useful to setup the [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

- https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-creating-a-model.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Used Visual Studio version: Community 2017 (15.9.5)

Comment: @Irfan Yusanif, does this way of querying let you fetch the records or there are other problems?

Answer (score 0):

the following should work if I understand what you're looking for correctly...

```
query = db.ads.Where(x => keywords.Contains(x.title));
```

Comment: This query will return 0 results. I have to do `title.contains(keywords.any())`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same bug with `MySql.Data.Entity` `v6.10.9`. Oddly, it only happened when the array had only 1 value. If my array had two or more values, it generated the correct SQL. Therefore, my method ended up looking something like:

```
var query = null;
if (1 == keywords.Length) {
  // MySql.Data.Entity bug creates invalid SQL with only one value
  var keyword = keywords[0];
  query = dbContext.ads.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(keyword)));
} 
else {
  query = dbContext.ads.Where(x => keywords.Any(y => x.Title.Contains(y)));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
query = db.ads.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(x.Keywords));
```

or:

```
var title= db.ads.Select(x=>x.title).ToList();
query = db.ads.Where(x => title.Contains(x.keyword));
```

Comment: In first query, `keywords` is a separate array as mentioned in question, its not part of `db.ads`.
And in second query, I cannot do `tolist()` as data is huge. and again you're making `keyword` a part of `db.ads`