# LINQ in List<List<string>> ANY function doesn't give correct response

Tags: c#, list, linq, search, any

Losing my mind, tried it with something more simple and the function ANY does work ofcourse.
I realise I don't need to convert X,Y to strings, but it didn't work either with points.
Function 'Distinct' isn't an option, I filter those coordinates from a much larger class. This function is a simple check to not add doubles, to avoid a really complex LINQ function.

[image: Search this item in the list, if it contains it, don't add it, if it doesn't contain it, add the item]

```
        public static List<PXML_DocumentOrderProductSlabOutline> FilterMountpart21(List<PXML_DocumentOrderProductSlabOutline> Mountpart21Lijst)
    {
        List<PXML_DocumentOrderProductSlabOutline> Gefilterd = new List<PXML_DocumentOrderProductSlabOutline>();
        List<List<string>> GefilterdeSparingen = new List<List<string>>();

        for (int x = 0; x < Mountpart21Lijst.Count; x++)
        {
            var ShapeMountpart21Lijst = Mountpart21Lijst[x].Shape.First().SVertex;
            List<string> LijstVertex = new List<string>();
            foreach (var xyz in ShapeMountpart21Lijst)
            {
                string Punt = Convert.ToInt32(xyz.X) + ";" + Convert.ToInt32(xyz.Y);
                LijstVertex.Add(Punt);
            }

             //This fails
            if(!GefilterdeSparingen.Any(abc => abc == LijstVertex))
             //  

            {
                GefilterdeSparingen.Add(LijstVertex);
                Gefilterd.Add(Mountpart21Lijst[x]);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ResultaatFilterMountpart21(LijstVertex, GefilterdeSparingen));
            }
        }
        return Gefilterd;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that `List` is a reference type, and by doing `abc == LijstVertex` you're equalling trying to check if `abc` is the same reference (i.e points to the same object in memory) as `LijstVertex`, which it of course never is since you're never adding `LijstVertex` to `GefilterdeSparingen `

Comment: I finally understand why, I don't see how I can compare the content then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656582/linq-query-to-find-if-items-in-a-list-are-contained-in-another-list