# check if a item in list, exists in another list with linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i'm new in c# ,sorry for bad question.

how can i say, if an item in a list,

exists in another list?

l know it can be done using **linq** functions, but I don't know which method can help.

I want something like this:

```
bool Exists(List<int> list1, List<int> list2)

{
    // if the value of the first index of list1 exists in list2, return true.

}
```

Comment: `return list2.Contains(list1[0]);` maybe check if the lists have items before returning to avoid index out of bound

Comment: I took the title of your question, did an internet search, and the first SOF answer came up.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656582/linq-query-to-find-if-items-in-a-list-are-contained-in-another-list   So I am not trying to be mean, but a good "rule of thumb" is "hmm, I wonder if anyone has probably already asked this before" and do a search for that.  That way, SOF avoid "extra clutter".

Comment: @granadaCoder you are right, my bad:(

Comment: `list1.Any() && list2.Contains(list1.First())`

Comment: @Me3nTaL - List‘s Contain method wouldn’t me LINQ though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well

you can do this

```
bool Exists(List<int> list1, List<int> list2)
{
var firstIndex=list1.First();

return list2.Any(num=> num == firstIndex);
}
```